# Dispersion relation of a medium

Tags: waves, dispersion

In a dispersive medium I have a wave equation:
$$
\frac{\partial^2E}{\partial z^2} + \eta \frac{\partial^4E}{\partial z^4} - \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2E}{\partial t^2}=0.
$$
How can I find the dispersion relation for this medium? Nothing else is given.

Comment: Note that we use MathJax to typeset mathematics; you can find a good tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). I have edited your first question for you $-$ please use this notation in future posts. (I have also changed your notation from $\frac{\delta^2E}{\delta z^2}$ and similar to the more usual $\partial$ notation, which is typeset as `\partial`. If you want to retain the original notation for some reason (?), feel free to roll it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are seeking dispersion relation, you can insert your solution into your wave equation. You can assume your wave function is

$$
\psi(x,t) = Ae^{i(kx-\omega(k)t)}
$$

Or just put $ A\cos(kx-\omega(k)t)$, it is up to you.

When you take derivatives you will find a relation between $\omega$ and $k$.
Your equation contains dispersive terms, you will get an extra terms instead of getting non dispersive relation, which is 
$$
\omega(k) = vk.
$$